# Hide databind element on control page .ascx

Tags: asp.net, data-binding, if-statement, suppress

Here is my code:

```
<h6><%#Eval("Category").ToString().ToUpper()%></h6>
```

I want to say that if the Category = "Construction" do not return that text. The h6 tag will be blank.

This is on the ascx page.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a ternary expression inside the binding:

```
<h6><%# Eval("Category").ToString() == "Construction" ? "" : Eval("Category").ToString().ToUpper()%></h6>
```

Or make a helper method for slightly cleaner syntax:

```
<script runat="server" language="C#">
    public string GetCategoryLabel(string category)
    {
        return "Construction".Equals(category, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) ? "" : category.ToUpper();
    }
</script>

<h6><%# GetCategoryLabel(Eval("Category").ToString()) %></h6>
```

Comment: I found it worked like this:                                                                   <%# Eval("Category").ToString().ToUpper() != "CONSTRUCTION" ? "" : Eval("Category").ToString().ToUpper()%>                                                                     I used !=

Comment: @user2600293 oh ... the comparison needs to be case-insensitive, I guess?